# How to I delete a data from an array

Tags: php

Please I need to delete or update a data stored in an array for example:

```
$array = ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
$data_to_delete = 'Tuesday';
//possible explanation of code to run
if(in_array($data_to_delete, $array)){
    //run code to delete $data_to_delete from the $array
}
```

Comment: [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) potentially?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks Jon... That's what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(($i = array_search($data_to_delete, $array, true)) !== false) {
    unset($array[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the unset() command.

So to delete "Tuesday" you use:

```
$key = array_search("Tuesday", $array); 
if( $key !== false ) {
    unset(array_search("Tuesday", $array));
}
```

If you didn't know, array_search() returns key of the string it has found, so it is the equivalent of:

```
unset($array[1]);
```